# Delete the expired or invalid openiddict tokens used in azure function

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, openiddict

I am working on an azure function which is a part of a system. The authentication/ authorization of system is controlled by `OpenIdDict` library. After using our system for sometime in our production, there are millions of invalid and expired tokens in the `OpenIddictTokens` table which I believe is causing some of the calls in our system to slowdown.

Now I am working on a time triggered azure function whose purpose is to delete (get rid of) all the useless tokens & authorizations saved in the `OpenIddictTokens` and `OpenIddictAuthorizations` tables respectively.

I started looking at the [openiddict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core) documentation and api but could not find the exact match for my requirements related to implementation in azure yet.

Can someone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into the documentation and experimenting with code, I was able to find the method and how to use this in my azure functions app.

First add the dependency for openiddict in startup:

```
        builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
        // Register the OpenIddict core services.
        .AddCore(options =>
        {
            // Register the Entity Framework stores and models.
            options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                .UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
        });
```

Then create the respective function with the `IOpenIddictAuthorizationManager` and `IOpenIddictTokenManager` as dependencies and call the `PruneAsync` method for both.

```
    private readonly IOpenIddictAuthorizationManager _openIddictAuthorizationManager;
    private readonly IOpenIddictTokenManager _openIddictTokenManager;

    public PruneTokenFunction(IOpenIddictAuthorizationManager openIddictAuthorizationManager, IOpenIddictTokenManager openIddictTokenManager)
    {
        _openIddictAuthorizationManager = openIddictAuthorizationManager;
        _openIddictTokenManager = openIddictTokenManager;
    }

    [FunctionName("prunetoken")]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * ")] TimerInfo timerInfo)
    {
        await _openIddictTokenManager.PruneAsync(DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-1));
        await _openIddictAuthorizationManager.PruneAsync(DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-1));
    }
```

Also following is the issue related to same query which might be helpful to many. [Implement automatic expired token flushing](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/361)